# Populating ScrollView with TextViews, Android Eclipse

Tags: android, sql, eclipse, scrollview

Here is a segment from my .xml layout file:

```
<ScrollView 
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_height = "300dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statementdatetv"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:text="DATE"
        android:textSize="10dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statementlocationtv"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:text="LOCATION" android:textSize="10dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statementshoptypetv"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:text="SHOPTYPE" android:textSize="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statementpricetv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:text="PRICE" android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="10dp"/>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The TextViews inside the ScrollView are to be populated from an SQL database. Everything worked fine before the ScrollView was added in, but afterwards it just came up with an error?

Unfortunately I don't know which error, is it just not possible to populate the values from an SQL database into a TextView which is inside a ScrollView?

The reason why I want to have a ScrollView is because a lot of Data could be outputted, and I want it to all be on the same page, therefore a ScrollView was the perfect (or so I thought) solution!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, by using ListView

```
MyAdapter adapteres;
 list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.grp_list);
db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
contacts = db.getAllContacts();
adapteres = new MyAdapter(getBaseContext(), (ArrayList<Contact>) contacts);
list.setAdapter(adapteres);
```

and Here MyAdapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Button btn;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Contact> contact;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;


    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
        this.context = context;
        this.contact = contacts;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);       
    }

    public int getCount() {

        return contact.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return contact.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, parent, false);  
        }

        Contact item = contact.get(pos);


        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
        name.setText(item.getName());


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show some records from DB, probably the best way is using ListViev instead of ScrollView. You should find plenty of examples for ListViev, CursorAdapter on the net.

Comment: Thanks for the help, realised that it can be done if you simply set the TextViews height to "wrap_content", obviously allowing the height to increase, therefore the ScrollView to be used as the number of rows to output increases!

Answer (score 0):

use a LinearLayout inside scroll view.
:)

```
<ScrollView 
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_height = "300dp" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statementdatetv"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:text="DATE"
        android:textSize="10dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statementlocationtv"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:text="LOCATION" android:textSize="10dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statementshoptypetv"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:text="SHOPTYPE" android:textSize="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statementpricetv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:text="PRICE" android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```